# Triggering Android 10 Theme Update for Widget layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, android-dark-theme

With the release of Android 10, several widgets (Gmail, Google News, Samsung Email) now update their theme when Dark mode is toggled. I am trying to replicate that behavior. I have a listview widget with an AppWidgetProvider and RemoteViewsFactory. However, when the dark mode is toggled, the ListView items toggle to the dark theme, but not the layout itself:

**Dark mode off:**

[image: Dark mode off]

**Dark mode on:**

[image: Dark mode on]

In my code, I am setting the layout in the OnUpdate() method in the AppWidgetProvider:

```
    override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray?
) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Updating Transaction Widget")

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO ) {
        updateTransactionTable(context)
        for (i in appWidgetIds!!.indices) {
            val layout: RemoteViews = buildLayout(context, appWidgetIds[i])
            appWidgetManager!!.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], layout)
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
    }
}
```

onUpdate is not called when dark mode is toggled. However, I cannot seem to find *any* method that is called within the AppWidgetProvider when the dark mode is toggled so I am not sure where to call a new layout build and even how to detect when a change is needed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `val isNight = (context.resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)  == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES` But if you use this context to inflate the views it should look good automatically. See, the inside already respects dark theme. The widget background should use theme attributes instead of a specific color. It's really hard to tell without the layout and background XML.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the Android system doesn't call any methods on the widget provider when the user changes the theme of the device.

What the system does is look for dark variants of your assets in '-night' resource folders.

Therefore, the solution is to create different assets for light and dark variants. For example:

- Light asset: 'widget_layout.xml' with light background in 'layout' resource folder.
- Dark asset: 'widget_layout.xml' with dark background in 'layout-night' resource folder.

Remember that it's also possible to create '-night' variants for drawables and other resource files, so depending on the case it might not be necessary to duplicate the whole layout (for example, I'm using a drawable as my background and I just needed to create a '-night' variant for that drawable).